# Files form Domina are automatically deleted

Tags: security

Files get automatically deleted from hosting account. 
How do i go about finding if its a virus on hosting or if someone with malicious intentions has hacked our hosting. 
How do i go about finding cause for this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your question is far too general... basically this is a job for a foresic/security analyst... which would in turn need adminitrative (and usually physical) access to the machine...

What you can do:

- Check whether there are any accounts that don't belong there
- Check for beckground processes like cron/scheduler etc.
- Check for viruses/rootkits etc.
  This might yield nothing since for a real check you need to boot from a medium which is 100% virus-free
- Change ALL passwords to new and very secure ones
- Check all logs

Comment: if i look at the log files...what should i be looking for in them

Comment: @shazia anything out of the ordinary... as I said: this is a job for a specialist...